# Graph Request Only Works With My Facebook Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web page which asks the user to log in and then proceeds to get JSon via Graph for a particular Facebook group. It builds the Uri dynamically by taking the access_token that is returned after login. It works fine when I do this, but if I try to log in with a different account, no data for the feed is returned.

One hint in this problem is when the facebook dialog screen appears, it only asks for my username/password. It doesn't ask go to the usual screen where Facebook asks for you to give permissions for "Basic Information" etc. It's just a username/password screen and then I go straight in.

This is the login code:

```
    function login()
    {
        FB.login(function (response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                // connected
                var authResponse = response.authResponse;
                access_token = authResponse.accessToken;
                refresh();
            } else
            {
                // cancelled
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> One hint in this problem is when the facebook dialog screen appears,
>   it only asks for my username/password. It doesn't ask go to the usual
>   screen where Facebook asks for you to give permissions for "Basic
>   Information" etc. It's just a username/password screen and then I go
>   straight in.

This is because you've already authorized the app, so once you login it will take you straight to the app.

> It works fine when I do this, but if I try to log in with a different
>   account, no data for the feed is returned.

Well the limited view of code you posted is fine, so something else is the problem. First debug step is to get the access token for that different account, and check the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if its tied to the appropriate user and scope.